# How to run a script once error handlers for all script tags have finished?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few resources that I load with `defer` from a cdn, like so:

```
<script src="js/sri-fallback.js"></script>
<script defer
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
      data-fallback="js/jquery.min.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous" onerror="resource_error(this)"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        defer
        data-fallback="js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous" onerror="resource_error(this)"></script>
<script src="js/do_jquery_stuff.js" defer></script>
```

`sri-fallback.js` is a script that I am trying to use to automatically handle failure when loading from a cdn (such as incorrect hash or cdn being down). It looks like this:

```
function resource_error(element) {
    var fallback_url = element.dataset.fallback;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = fallback_url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This mostly works, but the problem is that resources are loaded in this order:

1. Jquery via cdn (fails)
2. Bootstrap via cdn (fails)
3. do_jquery_stuff.js (succeeds)
4. Jquery locally (succeeds)
5. Bootstrap locally (succeeds)

This means that `do_jquery_stuff.js` fails because it depends on jquery, which is not loaded when it runs.

**How can I run `do_jquery_stuff.js` only when all scripts have loaded?**

Answer (score 0):

As you're handling the failure of loading a file by your own js, I think the only solution here is to make your `do_jquery_stuff.js` also be runned dynamically, after you checked all the scripts have been loaded.

One solution I see, is to also bind a `onload` event on each of your deferred scripts to a new function of your `sri-fallback.js`. That way, you'll be able to know which scripts have succeeded, which have failed, and you'll also know when every of them finally succeed. You'll have to count how many scripts have to be loaded.

Once you know every script has been loaded successfully, append your `do_jquery_stuff.js` to the page dynamically.